# Lightning Tab won't open fully on load

Tags: lightning, rerender, tab

I have a Lightning Component with a drop-down of quarters (Jan-March,..,Oct-Dec). Based on the quarter chosen I have to display lightning tabs, with the number of tabs and labels for the tabs being driven from server call.

While on load(for quarter:Jan-March) all tabs are displayed properly, on changing the drop-down value the component rerenders with the correct number of tabs and labels but the tabs do not load in opened state.

What could I be missing here.

> Component:

```
<aura:component controller="Blitz_QuarterlyUtility" >
<aura:attribute name="quarters" type="String[]"/>
<aura:attribute name="iterKeys" type="String[]"/>
<aura:attribute name="selTabId" type="String" />
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>

<lightning:layout>
    <lightning:layoutItem size="11">
        <div class="slds-page-header">Quarterly Information</div>
    </lightning:layoutItem>
    <lightning:layoutItem size="1">
        <lightning:select name="selectedQuarter" label="" aura:id="selectedQuarter" onchange="{!c.onfilterChange}">
            <aura:iteration items="{!v.quarters}" var="quarter">
                <option value="{!quarter.value}">{!quarter.label}</option>
            </aura:iteration>
        </lightning:select>
    </lightning:layoutItem>
</lightning:layout>

 <lightning:tabset variant="scoped" selectedTabId="{!v.selTabId}">
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.iterKeys}" var="key">   
        <lightning:tab label="{!key}" id="{!key}">
        HIDDEN FOR SOME QUARTERS
        </lightning:tab> 
   </aura:iteration> 
</lightning:tabset>
```

> Controller:

```
({
doInit : function(component, event, helper) 
{
    helper.fetchTabDetails(component,event,true);
},

onfilterChange: function(component,event,helper)
{
    helper.fetchTabDetails(component,event,false);
}
```

})

> Helper:

```
({
fetchTabDetails : function(component,event,isInit) {
    var action = component.get("c.fetchQuarterData");
    var today = new Date();
    var currentQuarter = Math.floor((today.getMonth() + 3) / 3);
    var quarter;      
    if(isInit)
    {
        var opts = [
        { value: 0, label: "Jan-March" }, 
        { value: 1, label: "April-June" }, 
        { value: 2, label: "July-Sept"},
        { value: 3, label: "Oct-Dec"}];
        var i=currentQuarter;
            while(i<=3)
            {
                opts.pop();
                i++;
        }
        component.set("v.quarters",opts);
        quarter =0;
    }
    else
    {
        quarter=component.find("selectedQuarter").get("v.value");
    }   
    action.setParams({  quarter : parseInt(quarter)});
    action.setCallback(this,function(response){
        var state = response.getState();
        var iKeys=[]; 
        if(state=="SUCCESS")
        {                                   
            for(var i=0;i<response.getReturnValue().length;i++)
            {
                var mapKey =response.getReturnValue()[i].Service_Line__c;
                iKeys.push(mapKey);
            }
            component.set("v.iterKeys",iKeys);                
            component.set("v.selTabId",iKeys[0]); 
        }
    });        
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
```

})